# Spacelike and timelike photons

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles

I know the definition of space-like and time-like intervals. How do you show that in some reaction the virtual photon(s) is spacelike/timelike?

**On page 191 Peskin and Schroeder, it says "since $q^2<0$ for a scattering process..." Why is this statement true? I don't see it straight away**

[For example in Bahba scattering discussed on this page.](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=372021)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose a scattering process with a 3- particle  vertex : $A \to  B + \gamma$. Here we suppose that particles $A$ and $B$ are massive, with the same mass $m$, and  $\gamma$ is the "virtual" photon. Let $a,b, q$ be the momenta of the particles $A,B,\gamma$.

You have :

$q^2 
=(a-b)^2 \\= (a_0 - b_0)^2 - ( \vec a - \vec b)^2
\\=(a_0^2 - \vec a^2) + (b_0^2 - \vec b^2) - 2(a_0b_0 - \vec a . \vec b )
\\=2(m^2-a_0b_0 + \vec a . \vec b)$

We may always choose a frame where $\vec a = - \vec b, a_0=b_0$, so we get :

$q^2 = 2(m^2-a_0^2-\vec a^2)= 4(m^2-a_0^2) < 0$

Comment: Nicely explained! @dmckee Please don't get this the wrong way, but when you have 200 other stuff to calculate one might not have the time to derive the simpler almost trivial stuff like my question here. Hence it's sometimes nice to have it derived for you although I know this is not the way to go (most of the time). Thanks to both!

Answer (score 4):

The same way you determine if the interval is space-like or time-like. In fact you do it by computing the square of the four-momentum and examining the sign.

Which sign is space-like and which time-like is a matter of convention, and varies from source to source. I like to compute the squared-interval as
$$ (\Delta s)^2 = (\Delta t)^2 - (\Delta \vec{x})^2 \,,$$
and therefore the square of the four momentum as
$$ q^2 = E^2 - \vec{p}^2 \,,$$
(where $E$ and $p$ are those of the exchange particle) so positive is time-like and negative is space-like.

Of course I often actual use $Q^2 = -q^2$ as the figure of merit, so the signs change again, but that just reflect the kind of reaction I was working on at the start of my career.

Comment: So why is babha -scattering timelike/spacelike as they suggest in the link I provided?

Comment: Look at the scattering in the CoM frame. Momentum is exchanged and energy is not (that's why I chose the CoM frame), so the scattering is clearly space-like.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I will accept the answer after I do what you suggested (tomorrow).

Comment: On page 191 Peskin and Schroeder, it says "since $q^2<0$ for a scattering process..." Why is this statement true? I don't see it straight away.

Comment: Use the center of momentum frame for this. Really. Compare and contrast with Drell-Yan.