# What do they mean with: photon scattering with $q^2=-Q^2\leq 0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering, metric-tensor

In a scattering problem, let q denote the four-momentum of the photon. Is $q^2=-Q^2\leq 0$ simply a statement of what metric one uses and simultaneously a definition of $Q^2$?

Comment: You should clarify what trace the metric tensor has or equivalently if this is a time-like of space-like 4-momentum transfer. In the texts I use this would be a time-like value and the process involved would be Drell-Yan like.

Comment: It's from an article with no statement about trace of metric. That's why I think the two conditions imply a specific metric. Don't they?

Comment: The use of $Q^2 = -q^2$ is usually a particle physics thing which would mean that this is a time-like virtual photon, but I don't think this alone proves anything.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83141/spacelike-and-timelike-photons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you're half right:

- The $-Q^2 = q^2$ part is a definition of $Q^2$.
- It's standard in particle physics (and, in particular, in the domains where one defines $Q^2 = -q^2$) to use the metric $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$, so that $m^2 = E^2 - p^2$ for an on-shell particle. Given this, $-Q^2 \leq 0$ is a statement that the virtual photon has $(\vec{q}_\gamma)^2 > E_\gamma^2$, i.e. that it carries spacelike four-momentum. You can see how that calculation works in e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83185/124).

Comment: Yes, that answer is also to a question of mine.