# Spacelike 4-momentum vector of virtual photon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, path-integral, virtual-particles

I want to ask is it generally true (or an axiom) that all virtual photon $q$ carry spacelike 4-momentum $q^2<0$, and hence it has corresponding 'imaginary' mass.

As it is always "internal", and yet not external, hence we can never observe/measure this photon in real world.

If a virtual photon carries timelike 4-momentum, hence it has real mass, what is the problem?

Comment: Related question: [Spacelike and timelike photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83141/spacelike-and-timelike-photons)

Comment: @Ghoster thanks for your help. I want to follow-up, Are there any off-shell photon that have $q^2>0$, I meant, in more complicated situations that involves more particles, can we always choose a reference frame such that we can show that off-shell photons all carries negative $q^2$?

Comment: Virtual photons are not real particles. They are mathematical tools used to perform perturbation theory. They also have nothing to do with QFT because you get similar terms when you write down the solution to a classical field equation order by order.

Comment: $q^2$ is a Lorentz invariant, and therefore its value is the same in all Lorentz frames. When an electron and a positron annihilate to produce a virtual photon, which then pair-produces a quark and antiquark, that virtual photon is timelike.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks very much, that means off shell photon can be time-like or space-like and it depends on what kind of process we are talking about.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.